# Running an EXE on an AWS Instance for game hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, hosting, exe

**Just looking to be pointed in the right direction here!**

I have an old "Playerworlds" MMO game that I'd like to set up a semi-permanent host onto an AWS instance.

The software is from 2008, and requires an EXE file to be started in order to start the environment.

In AWS, what type of setup should I use for this type of application hosting? Is there a solution with a UI like a Virtual Machine I can log into at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [Windows Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/prereqs-operating-systems.html#prereqs-os-windows-server) instances of EC2's easily enough.  You will use [RDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/understanding-remote-desktop-protocol) to log in and manipulate the machine.  I'll admit I don't know if Windows Server 2012 will run the software - fire up an instance and give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great.

Now I just need to figure out how to route my traffic in Windows Server... I can connect using a client app to my EC2 instance, but within the EC2 instance runs my EXE mentioned in this thread, which has connection settings defaulting to an internal private IP + Port within my Windows instance. Any idea how I can route incoming requests to that? @stdunbar